# replace values by keys and send it in a json

Tags: arrays, express, underscore.js

I would like to iterate on an array of object, replace all key's values with a different string (all values with the key FirstName will be "aaaa", and LastName will be "bbbbb") and send it to the client side via json response.

```
let data = [{
"id": "1",
"FirstName": "John",
"LastName": "Doe",
 }, {
"id": "2",
"FirstName": "Jane",
"LastName": "Doe",

 }
 ];
```

i'm using underscore .each method with this recursive function

```
 function filter (obj, key, value) {
     _(obj).each(function (v, k) {
       if (k === key) {
        obj[k] = value
       } else if (typeof v == 'object') {
        filter(obj[k], value,key)
    }
});
return {}

 }
```

and if i'm using it like that it works, console.log(data) and everything replaced as intended.

```
 filter(data, 'FirstName', "aaaa");
 filter(data, 'LastName', "bbbb");
```

but when i'm trying to use it on express router.get it sends the data unchanged
(please note that the data array is coming from model.allData)

```
 router.get('/route1',
function (req, res) {
    if (req.query) {
        model.allData(req.query,
            function (error, data) {
                if (error) {
                    res.status(500).json({message: error});
                } else {
                    return (function (filter) {
                        filter(data, 'FirstName', "aaaa");
                        filter(data, 'LastName', "bbbb")
                        res.status(200).json({data:filter})
                    });

                }
            });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

using: **ES6** **Spread Operator**:

```
router.get('/route1',
   function (req, res) {
   if (req.query) {
      model.allData(req.query,
        function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                res.status(500).json({message: error});
            } else {
                let filter = structureArray.map(o =>
                    ({ ...o, "FirstName": "aaaa","LastName":"bbbb" }));
                res.status(200).json({data: filter});
                };

            }
        });
}
});
```